# GLEW not available in declaration file, but works in header file CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

As stated in the title, I have configured CMake to link GLEW with my project, and have `#include <GL/glew.h>` in a .hpp file with no issue. The issue arises when trying to use GLEW functions in the declaration (`.cpp`) file associated with the header file, which gives me the error `identifier "xxx" is undefined` with `xxx` being the variety of functions I am trying to use.

Furthermore, I have also linked SDL2 in a similar manner, and have run into no issues in using its functions in the same declaration file. I believe the issue must be in my CMakeLists.txt configuration:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(PROJECT GUI_Engine)

add_executable (${PROJECT} "./src/driver/main.cpp")

set(HEADER_FILES ./src/include)
set(DEC_FILES ./src/lib)
set(PKGPATH C:/dev/vcpkg/packages)

add_library(engine ${DEC_FILES}/engine.cpp ${HEADER_FILES}/engine.hpp)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PKGPATH}/sdl2_x64-windows)
find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PRIVATE engine SDL2::SDL2main)
target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC SDL2::SDL2)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PKGPATH}/glew_x64-windows)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(engine PUBLIC GLEW::GLEW)
```

For reference, engine is the label associated with the `.hpp` and `.cpp` files I have been referencing.

For further testing, I have tried to `#include <GL/glew.h>` in my `.cpp` file, and receive the error `cannot open source file "GL/glew.h"`. Also, when using any GLEW function in my `.hpp` file, no error arises.

**UPDATE**
My IDE came out with an update today, as well as the associated build tools, with this update, I no longer am having this issue!

Comment: "my .cpp file" is ambiguous: are you talking about that in the engine or in the driver? Because there is **no** link between driver and engine, and therefore no link between driver and GLEW.

Comment: Please should us what the includes look like, and what the compiler output is. Sometimes IDEs get confused. Post some of the specific compiler errors.

Comment: @Botje "For reference, engine is the label associated with the .hpp and .cpp files I have been referencing." Similarly, there is a link between driver and engine.